# Xpath 1.0 Reference Original Context from Sibling Axes

Tags: xpath

Using XPath 1.0, and given the following XML:

```
<Root>
<Line ID="1">
    <Key>1</Key>
    <Value>10001</Value>
</Line>
<Line ID="2">
    <Key>2</Key>
    <Value>10020</Value>
</Line>
<Line ID="3">
    <Key>1</Key>
    <Value>10300</Value>
</Line>
<Line ID="4">
    <Key>2</Key>
    <Value>14000</Value>
</Line>
</Root>
```

I need to be able to sum the values of all the lines that match the key of the "current" line being checked. So assuming the context is `/Root/Line[2]`, then the sum should be 24020.

Unfortunately, using following/preceding sibling axes results in not being able to back reference the original "self" to predicate the key. Ex: `following-sibling::Line[Key=./Key]/Value` would return 10300 instead of 14000 because `.` is the current node on the sibling axes. I can't figure out how I would reference back to the original context?

Comment: Why `14020`? If you want to add `10020` and `14000` I would expect `24020`.

Comment: And XPath 1.0 supports variables, if your API supports that then doing e.g. `sum($context/../Line[Key = $context/Key]/Value)` would do. If your API does not allow you to set up variable bindings then I am not sure it is possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I was just showing that from the context of line 2, trying to get a following-sibling that matches the Key doesn't return the node set I need (so the sum would also be wrong).

Comment: I'll look into the possibility of using variables in case there isn't any way to natively do what I need, thanks for that tip.

Comment: I retract my first comment.. You were right on my bad math.